How should I get FocusState from ChildView to ParentView in SwiftUI?
I have a problem how to deal with FocusState in my project.
My parent View has an enum created on top:
enum RegistrationFocus: Hashable {
case username, password, confirmPassword, nameAndSurname, email, confirmEmail, phoneNumber
}

And I have a focusState variable inside my struct
@FocusState var focus: RegistrationFocus?

My childview is in a VStack to display all views. (only wrote 3 down there for now)
PersonalUserDetailsRow(title: "UserName", text: $registerModel.username, textContentType: .username, focus: $focus, focusfield: .username)
PersonalUserDetailsRow(title: "Password", text: $registerModel.password, textContentType: .newPassword, focus: $focus, focusfield: .password)
PersonalUserDetailsRow(title: "Confirm Password", text: $registerModel.confirmPassword, textContentType: .confirmPassword focus: $focus, focusfield: .confirmPassword)

And my ChildView looks like this:
struct PersonalUserDetailsRow: View {

var title: String
@Binding var text: String
let textContentType: UITextContentType
var focus: FocusState<RegistrationFocus?>.Binding
@State var focusField: RegistrationFocus?

var body: some View {

if textContentType == .newPassword {

SecureField(title, text: $text)

.padding(.top, 15)

.disableAutocorrection(true)

.textContentType(textContentType)

.focused(focus.projectedValue, equals: focusField)

Divider() .overlay(Color.black)

So my child view does contain var focus: FocusState<RegistrationFocus?>.Binding and State focusField: RegistrationFocus?
But I have no clue how to use those 2.
I want to go to the next textField when the user taps the return key on keyboard.
I have seen many examples where people use 2 textfields in Parent view and i understand those examples and how to move around textFields when using .focused(, equals:).
But I can't find any examples how to do this with a child View, especially with this .focused(focus.projectedValue, equals: focusField) if it's even correct.
How should I do this so it will work?
I keep getting this error:
The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions. with the above code

I tried both of these:
var focus: FocusState<RegistrationFocus?>.Binding
@State var focusField: RegistrationFocus?

@binding var focusField doesn't work.
I don't really want to copy paste the textField and Divider() from child view 7 times in my parents view. I want to learn how to use the custom view with FocusState in my parents view.

The compiler error may or may not be connected to your issue. It is basically stating the struct is too complex. You have not posted complete structs, so nobody can help with this.

Change PersonalUserDetailsRow to set the next focus field when the field value is set:
struct PersonalUserDetailsRow: View {

var title: String
@Binding var text: String
// let textContentType: UITextContentType
@Binding var focus: RegistrationFocus?
let focused: RegistrationFocus
let nextFocused: RegistrationFocus

var body: some View {

// if textContentType == .newPassword {

SecureField(title, text: $text)

    .onSubmit {
        focus = nextFocused
    }

.padding(.top, 15)

.disableAutocorrection(true)

// .textContentType(textContentType)

.focused($focus, equals: focused)


Put into the initialiser the NEXT field you want to focus:
PersonalUserDetailsRow(title: "UserName", text: $registerModel.username, textContentType: .username, focus: $focus, focused: .username, nextFocused: .password)


Thank you for the fast reply. I added the parts now to my project, but i am geting an new error on this line : .focused(focus, equals: focused)
Cannot convert value of type 'RegistrationFocus' to expected argument type 'FocusState.Binding'
Not sure what to do.

Added missing $ in .focused($focus, equals: focused).

Thank you so much for your help. Now it works as intended.
